# Info.plist: MinimumOSVersion value is invalid

Tags: iphone, ios4, minimumosversion

I know there have been a few other people asking this question, but my situation is a bit different.

I'm getting this error whenever I build my app. I've tried looking at the .plist file that is generated and there isn't a value for the MinimumOSVersion key. My app runs just fine on the iPhones we test with, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what is causing the .plist to be set incorrectly.

Can anyone shed some light on this? I'm not sure what other info to post besides I'm building against 4.0 and targeting 3.2, building for both iPad and iPhone, and building for both arm6 and arm7.

Thanks,
Robbie

Comment: Have you defined the targeted devices only iPhone? Or also iPad? Maybe it's complaining because the min target SDK is not available on iPhone, and you may have set the device family iPhone. I'm just guessing. Cheers

Comment: Oh yeah, maybe you have changed the configs on the project settings, and not on the target. The target settings override the project settings. Make sure that theconfig issue right one on your target settings. This is not a guess :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MinimumOSVersion is supposed to be based on your iPhone OS Deployment Target.  Check that setting in your target's build properties to confirm that it's set to 3.2.

Even if it appears to be set properly, try changing it to something else and then changing it back to 3.2 at so that the value is explicitly set within your target build settings.  I've encountered an Xcode bug in the past where my MinimumOSVersion was getting set to a different value than my iPhone OS Deployment Target.  Explicitly setting the value in my target settings resolved the issue for me.

Comment: +1 -- it's a project build property, not a app plist property. Make sure to check both the build settings for your project and your target; the target settings override the project ones.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I forgot to look at the iPhone OS Deployment Target in my Target's settings. I found that it was set to be the compiler's default when in Release mode (the mode I'm building in) and 3.2 when in Debug mode. I'd give +2 if I could :)